# C# chain ?? operator for different types

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm implementing a ToString method for an object. The method looked like:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "E" + (myNum ?? SQLIndex) + STK.ExtraLabel(areaType);
}
```

Where myNum is a nullable int and SQLIndex is just an int.

but the powers be have decided that if SQLIndex isn't set yet (used to be = -1 if not set), we should put "NEW" instead of -1 there.

So I changed SQLIndex to a nullable int, but this code doesn't work because I'm guessing the ?? operator can't return both int and string, even though the int would be casted to a string:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "E" + (myNum ?? SQLIndex ?? "NEW") + STK.ExtraLabel(areaType);
}
```

I'm currently using a ternary operator to accomplish the same effect, but for readability's sake, is there any way to use the shortcut ?? operator here?

Comment: For readability you want to use the ternary operator? Why don't you use a `if` `else` statement for readability?

Comment: @Aron For readability he wants to use the [`??` (null-coalescing) operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to need to convert all of the expressions here into a single type.  In this case, `string` is really the type that you want to end up with, so you're going to have to *convert* (not cast) the integers into strings before using `??`.  You can use `ToString` to convert an integer into a string:

```
return "E" + (myNum?.ToString() ?? SQLIndex?.ToString() ?? "NEW") + STK.ExtraLabel(areaType);
```

Comment: @Servy I retract my previous statement, however it is worth pointing out that you need to run your code through a C#6 compiler to get the `?.` operator to compile.

Answer (score 3):

You could cast one of the operands to `object`:

```
return "E" + return "E" + (((object)myNum ?? SQLIndex) ?? "NEW") +  STK.ExtraLabel(areaType);
```

or

```
return "E" + return "E" + (myNum ?? (object)SQLIndex ?? "NEW") +  STK.ExtraLabel(areaType);
```

if you don't want the extra parentheses.

Comment: Since none of the operands to any of those `??` operator calls have side effects it's *irrelevant* which of the two is performed first, and which is performed second.  Having said that, the operators will be evaluated left to right, not right to left, so your parenthesis are redundant even if there are side effects.

Comment: @Servy The parens are _required_ in the first example or it won't compile - which indicates that it's evaluated from right-to-left since the compiler complains about the `int? ?? string` segment.  The second example is then `int? ?? (object ?? string)` which evaluates to `int? ?? object`

Comment: @Servy In any case I took out the section regarding associativity - the fact is the first requires parens, the second doesn't